# How to make the AsyncTask "doInBackground()" wait for an arraylist

Tags: java, android, sql, arraylist, android-asynctask

I want to save some objects in the local SQL DB on my android device.
If I try to run the app, I get a `null object reference` error on the cell ArrayList  in onPostExecute().

public class CellApiTask extends AsyncTask> {
    private Context context;

```
public CellApiTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Cell> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Fragment_Battery_Cell_Voltage cellVoltageClass = new Fragment_Battery_Cell_Voltage();
    return cellVoltageClass.getCellsForDB();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Cell> cell) {
    CellDbHelper dbHelper = new CellDbHelper(context);
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        try {
            /* delete old db if it exists */
            db.delete(CellEntryContract.CellEntry.TABLE_NAME_CELL, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e){
        }


        for (int i = 0; i<cell.size();i++) {

            values.put(CellEntryContract.CellEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_NUMBER, cell.get(i).getCellNo());
            values.put(CellEntryContract.CellEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_DENSITY, cell.get(i).getDensity());
            values.put(CellEntryContract.CellEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CELL_VOLTAGE, cell.get(i).getCellVoltage());
            db.insert(CellEntryContract.CellEntry.TABLE_NAME_CELL, null, values);
        }
        Log.i(CellStorage.class.toString(),"Cells successful saved");
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e(CellStorage.class.toString(), "Could not save cells in local data storage. ", ex);
    } finally {
        if (dbHelper != null)
            dbHelper.close();

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    amountOfCells = (((AnnualServiceActivity) getActivity()).getBatteryFromIntent().getCell().intValue());
    generateGrid();
    CellStorage cellStorage = new CellStorage(getContext());
    cellStorage.runCellApiTasks();
    return view;
}

....
public ArrayList<Cell> getCellsForDB() {
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCells; i++) {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.setCellNo(i + 1);
        cell.setCellVoltage(0);
        cell.setDensity(0);
        Log.i("öööööööööööö",cellsForDB.get(i).getCellNo()+"");
        cellsForDB.add(cell);
    }
    return cellsForDB;
}
...
```

I think the doInBackground(...) method finished befor the ArrayList is ready in getCellsForDB() maybe thats because I get the null object reference error. So is it possible to make the method wait until the ArrayList from getCellsForDB() is ready?

crash log:

```
    08-07 15:43:54.388 1585-1585/frontend.datastorage.CellStorage: Could not save cells in local data storage. 
                                                                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                                                  at CellApiTask.onPostExecute(CellApiTask.java:49)
                                                                                                                                  at CellApiTask.onPostExecute(CellApiTask.java:20)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
08-07 15:43:54.392 1585-1585/fronius.com.serviceapp_frontend E/class fronius.com.serviceapp_frontend.datastorage.CellStorage: Could not save cells in local data storage. 
                                                                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                                                  at CellApiTask.onPostExecute(CellApiTask.java:49)
                                                                                                                                  at CellApiTask.onPostExecute(CellApiTask.java:20)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: add your crash log

Comment: where did you instantiate cellsForDB?

Comment: @USKMobility I added the error log. I instantiate it in the Fragment onCreateView() Method

Comment: getCellsForDB this method is another class

Comment: Fragment_Battery_Cell_Voltage  is Fragment ? if yes until u not add/replace in fragment manager all onCreateView will not be called

Comment: @USKMobility what do you mean it is another class?

Comment: @ConstantinCerberus yes it is a fragment and will be added to the main screen

Comment: Add complete code of fragment.

Comment: @WeSt u creating new instance of your fragment in do in background oncreate() and oncreateview() will not be called  at this point as well all yours list.. will not be instantiate

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wait for anything here, the doInBackground method finishes its execution when cellVoltageClass.getCellsForDB() returns. getCellsForDB() seems to return null, **because cellsForDB is null** (the only reason you don't get the crash earlier is because amountOfCells is 0 and the for inside getCellsForDB() doesn't loop)

Comment: this sound correct. But if the Fragment was inserted first the amountOfCells is not 0 and it would run. How can I first finish the insertion of the fragments and then call the cellsForDB. I tried to call the doInBackground at the end of the onCreateView() of the Fragment but it doesn't work

Comment: keeping your app logic tied to fragment lifecycle events isn't a good approach, but you can do it in the first call to your fragment's onResume() - here you can be sure your fragment has been "inserted" and is now visible to the user.